# UDP packets buffer in Quatz Composer

Tags: macos, udp, quartz-composer

I am using an UDP network receiver in a quartz composition, and I have noticed that UDP packets may get lost if more than one are received during the rendering of a frame.
Is it possible to bufferize the UDP packets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as of 10.6, Quartz Composer's `Network Receiver` patch doesn't queue packets.  You'd need to write your own network receiver patch in order to do so.

Comment: Guess that's the best answer I can get